# Failed to create ICU collator, are ICU data files missing? for crosswalk

Tags: android, crosswalk

I'm using crosswalk lib for opening webGL URL.
And getting below fatal error for some 2D file.

Tried [this](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7009) workaround by removing android.webkit reference when we use crosswalk library.
But still getting same below error.

## Fatal error in , line 0

## Failed to create ICU collator, are ICU data files missing?

Same webGL URL is working in Android webView.

Any help would be appreciated.